# Unable to get coloured column header to excel for multiple pandas dataframes

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I want to write multiple dataframes to excel and also add color to column headers.
I have written below code to achieve this however, it colors only the column header for the first dataframe, but not the others.

```
# example data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(15).reshape(5, 3))

# adding _background_gradient style to df
styled_df = (df.style
             .background_gradient(subset=[0, 1], # background_gradient method
                                  low=0, high=0.5,
                                  cmap="YlGnBu"))

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'feature 1' : ['cat 1', 'cat 2', 'cat 3', 'cat 4'], 'feature 2' : [400, 300, 200, 100]
                  ,'feature 3' : [400, 300, 200, 100], 'feature 4' : [400, 300, 200, 100]})

#using below function to add color and write multiple dataframes to excel
def multiple_dfs(df_list, sheets, file_name, spaces):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name, engine = 'xlsxwriter')
    row = 0
    for dataframe in df_list:
        dataframe.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheets,startrow=row , startcol=0)   
        workbook = writer.book
        worksheet = writer.sheets[sheets]
        # Add a header format.
        header_format = workbook.add_format({
            'bold': True,
            'text_wrap': True,
            'fg_color': '#D7E4BC',
            'border': 1})
        # Write the column headers with the defined format.
        for col_num, value in enumerate(dataframe.columns.values):
            worksheet.write(0, col_num + 1, value, header_format)
        row = row + len(dataframe.index) + spaces + 2
    writer.save()

dfs = [styled_df,df2]
multiple_dfs(dfs,'Sheet1','output.xlsx',1)
```

[image: screenshot of output.xlsx]

Comment: You need to increment the row number in `worksheet.write()` for each dataframe. Currently it is 0 for each one so only the top row is being modified.